# Android Stroke Shape Drawable Left for TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

Following is my drawable xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/button_blue" />
```

Following is textView xml

```
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOrigin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/circle_cab"
                    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                    android:drawableTint="@color/deal_disc_bg"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="ksjkdjksjkdjkj"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

I found that drawable is not appearing on left side of textview

Then I have added following to drawable xml

```
   <size
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp" />
```

After adding this line I a getting drawable in left but it is drawing solid circle and not stroke

Any idea how to add stroke circle as drawable left to textview only through XML and not pragmatically.

[image]

Comment: Please add relevant output screenshots as well for more clarity.

Comment: and what do you expect if size is 2x2 dp?

Comment: tried other sizes as well

Comment: try just for testing stroke width 2px for example and size 8px and 8px

Comment: For me the circle is not full, it is hollow with the `<size>` attribute you specified.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all circle it is a stroke. what I Mean that you width of stroke is exactly the size (consider left stroke 1 and right stroke 1) to fix it try to increase the size or decrease the width of the stork.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/button_blue" />
```